# SelectPDF .Net Core 2.2: Exception: Conversion failure. Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement [SelectPdf](https://selectpdf.com/selectpdf-library-for-net-2019-vol-1-now-with-blink-rendering-engine/).
I am working on a OS X and I think that is why I am getting this problem:

> Exception: Conversion failure. Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libkernel32.dll, 1): image not found

Is there an alternative way for macOs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, this is a dependency to Windows kernel library.
If I believe https://selectpdf.com/docs/Installation.htm the .NET Core version is Windows only: ".NET Core version - Windows only" and "Note 2: The .NET Core version is for .NET Core 2.0 or above through .NET Standard 2.0. Currently it requires a Windows system to run. It does not work on Linux or Mac or Xamarin."