# Alpine Docker Missing kernel32.dll Library

Tags: .net, linux, docker, .net-core-3.1

I have a Docker container running Alpine Linux and hosting a .NET Core 3.1 Application. I am using a library called "SelectPdf". This library uses the "System.Drawing" .NET libraries. First, I was getting an error that the libgdiplus.dll could not be loaded. I fixed that with this line:

```
# Install libgdiplus for System.Drawing library
RUN yum install -y aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 glibc-devel libgdiplus
```

This removed that error, but I either that library "System.Drawing" or "SelectPdf" is making native windows calls and now I get this error:

```
  Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies.
```

Is there another install command I can use to add this .dll file to the build in my Docker file?

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently, when you get this error it means that it can only be run on a Windows machine/ windows base. The Kernel32.DLL is part of the Windows OS and can't be added like a .NET library. Specifically, the "SelectPDF" library is only supported on Windows and not MacOS or Linux as answered here.

[SelectPDF .Net Core 2.2: Exception: Conversion failure. Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275154/selectpdf-net-core-2-2-exception-conversion-failure-unable-to-load-shared-li)